# Why is rows() on a server-side DataTable not a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

Why is `rows()` not a function on a server-side datatable?

The tables works fine beside that.

I have used `rows()` on five other client-side datatables before without any problems.

```
var tableComputerAndDevice = $('#tableComputerAndDevices').dataTable({
    searching: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    language: {
        "processing": '<div style="background-color:#eee"> <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-5x"> </span> </div>'
    },
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: "POST"
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "checkbox", "searchable": false },
        { "data": "ComputerName", "searchable": true },
        { "data": "LastContact", "searchable": true }
    ]
});

var nodes = tableComputerAndDevice.rows('.selected').nodes();
console.log('nodes: ' + nodes);
```

**Error:** TypeError: tableComputerAndDevice.rows is not a function

Comment: wow, I just had to use "DataTable()" instead of "dataTable". I think :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you judged it correctly. You need to change the `dataTable` to `DataTable`

Also to state that there is a difference between dataTable and DataTable.

> The difference between the two is that the first will return a jQuery
>   object, while the second returns a DataTables API instance.

Comment: @radbyx:- I didnt see that you were answering your own question. Thats why I tried to add few more points to my answer. Anyways if you want I will delete my answer. :)

Comment: No we will go with your answer :) I appreciate another answer. It makes me feel complete safe now. Beside that you shared big wisdom of why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Change `dataTable` to `DataTable`. I answer my own question because I spent a hour with this bug, so I hope I can help others.

```
var tableComputerAndDevice = $('#tableComputerAndDevices').DataTable({
```